# sdkman appears to be installed but not showing up on my drive

Tags: groovy, sdkman

I have started learning groovy and I just came across the SDKMAN utility.
To give it a try I folllowed the installation guidelines at the official site of sdkman and tried to run the below command to install sdkman on Windows 10 :

```
set SDKMAN_DIR="E:/sdkman" && curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

But I donot see any **sdkman** folder present in my **E** drive.

When I try to re-run the command it says :

```
Looking for a previous installation of SDKMAN...
SDKMAN found.

======================================================================================================
 You already have SDKMAN installed.
 SDKMAN was found at:

    "E:/sdkman"
```

I am just confused as to why am I not able to see it with my eyes. I have even tried enabling **view hidden items**.

Tried to execute `which sdk`. but it clearly says   `which: no sdk in (..
...`

has anyone else experienced similar issue. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

which bash implementation are you using under windows? cygwin? gitbash?

I believe at least in gitbash that the path syntax is `/e/sdkman/`, i.e. you would do:

```
export SDKMAN_DIR="/e/sdkman" && curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

but it's been a long time since I was on windows and I suspect this is bash-implementation specific (i.e. it might differ between cygwin and gitbash for example).

If this assumption is correct, the syntax you were using might have created a directory called `E:/sdkman` under your user's home directory or whatever directory you happened to be in when you ran this. Just guessing here, but worth a look.